# Fullcalendar Resource View - move the blocks up to the top for efficient display

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

[image]

I've got a Fullcalendar implementation using the resource view fork by jarnok (http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/) working for my environment.

As you can see in the image, when many jobs are added to a single resource, they stack in such a way as to leave a lot of whitespace.

My objective is to calculate the position of the block based on if there is available whitespace above it and sort of smash these down visually to use as little vertical space as possible.

Specifically you can see this job for Sally in green could render on the top line without blocking anything.

Somewhere in the code is the render function (which I've found, but still can't make sense of) and it calculates the offset from the top or from the previous job.

Looking at the source code, can anyone point me in the right direction where these blocks actually get rendered from?  Then potentially I can adjust the logic to do a check if there is anything "above" the job on the top line, and if not, render it there.